# Check if cvRect is within cvMat

Tags: c++, opencv, bounding-box

I am using bounding boxes to find text in an image and sometimes the boxes are just slightly too small and cut off parts of text on the top and bottom.

[image]

So I thought I'd extend every bounding box just a little to compensate for the inaccuracy.

```
double Z = 10;
cv::Rect extended( appRect.x-Z, appRect.y-Z, appRect.width+2*Z, appRect.height+2*Z);
```

`appRect` being a `cv::Rect`

This does what I am looking for however it seems that sometimes it takes the bounding box out of bounds.

Giving me this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat
```

How can I check that the rect is within the boundaries of the image and avoid this error while still expanding the bounding boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, your `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` are not allowed to be negative.

Try to add a `std::max()` and `std::min()`:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::max && std::min

int Z = 10;
int x = std::max<int>(0, appRect.x-Z);
int y = std::max<int>(0, appRect.y-Z);
int w = std::min<int>(mat.cols - x, appRect.width+2*Z);
int h = std::min<int>(mat.rows - y, appRect.height+2*Z);
cv::Rect extended(x, y, w, h);
```

Or as [Iwillnotexist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809095/iwillnotexist-idonotexist) smartly suggested:

```
// expand
double Z = 10;
cv::Rect extended( appRect.x-Z, appRect.y-Z, appRect.width+2*Z, appRect.height+2*Z);

// intersect
extended &= Rect(Point(0, 0), mat.size());
```

Comment: Oh, I see thanks I'll get this a shot. Seems to be an elegant solution. I'll give this a shot after dinner! I'm getting an error `No matching call to 'max'`. It seems that the `appRect.x-Z` is some type of object not numeric value.

Comment: You're probably missing the include for std::max (which is "#include <algorithm>"). see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/ . The page also contains a reference implementation you could use.

Comment: Still seem to be getting the error even with the code snippet, any ideas?

Comment: try to enforce the type of the parameters `std::max<int>(0, appRect.x-Z)` or add some casts `std::max(0, (int)appRect.x-Z)`

Comment: @Nick Why not intersect the expanded `Rect` with the `Rect` representing the bounds of the matrix? Something a la `expandedRect &= Rect(Point(0, 0), mat.size())`? Much shorter and cleaner.